# Switched outlet with 2 black/2 white wires. Switch controls outlet and light fixture

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I have a switched outlet that I wanted to see if I could change it so it could be always live or even half hot.  A little background on is that it's in the bathroom and a light switch power on the outlet and a light fixture.

Another note, I also notice the ground wires are connected to the mounting bracket in the back instead, is that okay?

I tried to looking up a set up like mine but wasn't able to find much so I was seeing if I could get more information here about this particular set up.

Is it possible to do what I want above easily?

Let me know if more information is needed!

[image]
[image]
[image]

*Adding switch pictures:
Left is the light switch.  The right one controls the bathroom fan.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The same switch needs to be on for the lights and outlet to work?  A picture of the switch wires might help.  It looks like the whites and blacks are on the wrong side, blacks should be on the brass colour screws.

Comment: @crip659 - Yup the same switch controls the light and the outlet.  I noticed the black and white too but did not want to touch anything till I get more information/confirmations.
Added some pictures of switch too

Comment: I doubt you can change it without rewiring.  The switch probably passes power to the outlet and the outlet passes it to the lights.  There might be a way of doing it in the switch box, but will need to know all the cables.  There seems to be power and possibility of the outlet cable or light cable in there but need to know if outlet to light passes though there.

Comment: Thank you @crip659

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without running a new cable, it appears that the only way to get an unswitched outlet and have the light switched is to swap the outlet and the switch that supplies the power.

Bear with me here:

The switch that turns on the light and the outlet does so by providing power to the outlet. The outlet transfers the power to the light. (The light comes on because the outlet gets power. (neutral and hot are on the wrong sides of the outlet, but that can be changed...good catch crip659)   There is no constant hot in the box that the outlet is in.

Take out the switch. Replace it with an outlet. Tie the hot that was into the switch and the hot out together with a pigtail to power the outlet on a brass screw. Pigtail off the group of white neutrals to the outlet on to the silver screw.

You now have an outlet that is constant hot in the box with the switch for the fan.  You also have a constant hot into the box that the outlet was previously in.

You have 2 options:

It looks as if the outlet box is double gang. (You didn't say what else was in the box)  You could add another outlet in the box using the now constant hot with a pigtail and provide power to a switch that will now connect to the other remaining black wire and work the light.  Tie the 2 white neutrals together and pig tail to provide the neutral to the outlet.

The other option is to just put the 2 blacks on a switch to work the light and tie the 2 white neutrals together.  Put a 1/2 blank cover over everything.  ( But really why not have another outlet if you can.)

Comment: Okay thank you! I don't think I would be doing any swapping for now as that is a little out of my comfort level and scope.  I will however look into swapping the black and white wires to fix that issue.
Thank you!